# How to insert string into oracle clob type with Dapper?

Tags: oracle, dapper

I have a simple question about dapper with Oracle database, when I was trying to insert a large size of string into oracle clob, it throws exception says:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

then I was trying to modify this part

```
param.Add(name: "body", value: obj.BODY, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
```

I can't specify `OracleDbType.Clob`

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: If there is a way to do this in ado.net without explicitly referencing oracle, I'm all ears. However, another option is a custom parameter - a bit like DbString. That let's you control things more.

Comment: @MarcGravell Could you please provide code on custom parameter?

Comment: @MarcGravell Marc, could you give comments on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25175312/926460

Comment: To re-iterate: if there is a way of handling this nicely just using ADO.NET, I'd really love to see it; it is very vexing not being able to do things using just the abstract base types / interfaces: it kinda feels like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("body", obj.Body);` *should be enough*

Answer (score 3):

Its works for me...

```
byte[] newvalue = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(mystring);
var clob = new OracleClob(db);
clob.Write(newvalue, 0, newvalue.Length);

var parameter = new OracleDynamicParameters();    
parameter.Add("PCLOB", clob);


var command = @"Insert into MYTABLE(CLOBFIELD) values (:PCLOB)";
var t = db.Execute(command, parameter);
```

You could get OracleDynamicParameters class in https://gist.github.com/vijaysg/3096151

Answer (score 1):

Solution from this thread https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/142 :

```cs
// Install-Package Dapper.Oracle

string longString = "...";
byte[] longStringBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(longString);

OracleClob clob = new OracleClob(this.conn);
clob.Write(longStringBytes, 0, longStringBytes.Length);

OracleDynamicParameters dynamicParams = new OracleDynamicParameters();
dynamicParams.Add("fileContent", clob, OracleMappingType.Clob, ParameterDirection.Input);

this.conn.Execute("insert into someTable (fileContent) values (:fileContent)");
```

Answer (score 1):

For out software, we just cast the large string to an object and Dapper is saving it to the CLOB column as desired:

```
await _dbContext.ExecuteAsync(OurInsertSqlStatement,
    new {
           record.Id,
           record.Name,
           record.CategoryId,
           LargeString = record.LargeString as object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can solve your problem more easily by using
  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand instead of Dapper.
- The important point you should pay attention to in this section; When
  creating the query, you must place the parameters in the order of the
  columns in the database.

  ```
   var sql = "insert into Sample_Table (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_clob) values (:col_1_param, :col_2_param, :col_3_param, :col_clob)";

   conn.Open();

   OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, (OracleConnection)conn);

       cmd.Parameters.Add("col_1_param", col_1_value);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("col_2_param", col_2_value);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("col_3_param", col_3_value);
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("col_clob", col_clob_value) {                             
  OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob, Size = col_clob_value.Length });

  var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  conn.Close();
  ```